# Convert string value as variable name in js, like in php

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I would like to do this in JS,like in php, example.

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: This is a bad idea and you should stop wanting to do that.

Comment: Is not bad idea, that is saving me lot of repetitive lines of codes in php and I can do lot of kind of dynimic functions, saving many many lines of codes.

Comment: Nima Hakimi, thank you, I didn't saw that post.

Comment: @CarlosDiaz Any time you think you need to do this, you should be using an object instead.